# Git tags removed if I merge submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule and I plan to merge it into my main repo, but I have several tags that I want to keep. If I merge my submodule into my repo, would the tags that reference the submodule be messed up?

Comment: What if you create a copy of repositories and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags don't reference your submodule. They reference a commit that in it has a `.gitmodules` file that has information about your submodule. Your tags will not be affected. To use a tag after you merge your submodule into your main repo, you can edit your config so the submodule's url is the path to the repo itself. Now checking out a tag and doing a `submodule update` (don't do `--init` or it will clobber the just adjusted config) will make the tag usable.